Embbeded pdf viewer not adjourning
I’m new to LateX and I have the following issue :
Whenever I change my code the embedded pdf viewer is “stuck” and does not adjourn. Even if my code is correct and when I exit texstudio and open the pdf file everything appears as I wanted it to.
Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance !

Welcome! What do you mean by adjourn? Do you mean it does not refresh/reload the document? Is your document recompiled automatically? Do you have to exit TeX Studio to view the PDF? (Why?) Which OS are you on?

Hi ! Thank you for your answer ! My document is not recompiled automatically. I click on the “production and visualization” icon (a green double arrow) in orders to compile the document. By adjourn I mean that when I click on the “production and visualization” icon, the embedded pdf viewer does not show the visualisation. It stays stuck on a previous version. However, when I exit Texstudio and go into the folder where the pdf is, when I open it, the changes appear correctly. I just have to exit en re-open the document everytime I want to see if what I’ve done is correct. I’m on windows 10.

What happens if you try to open the PDF without exiting TeX Studio? Which OS are you on?

Hi, when I do that everything appears as wanted ! It’s only the pdf viewer that does not show the changes I made. I’ll try desinstalling and reinstalling everything.
(I’m on Windows 10)

So presumably it's a problem with the builtin PDF viewer. (I think TeX Studio uses a builtin viewer rather than a separate application?) If reinstalling doesn't work, it might be a bug, but I know nothing about Windows and don't use TeX Studio, so ....
